# Dump process memory in OS X 10.11

Tags: macos, sip, osx-elcapitan, gcore

I wrote a tool that dumps a specific section from a remote mach-o based process to a file.

However, after upgrading to El Capitan (10.11), it no longer works due to the SIP  feature that prevents me from using `task_for_pid`. This is intended to prevent code injection to remote signed processes.

However, I only need it for reading the remote process' memory space. Perhaps there exists some sort of alternative for the following code to work on 10.11?

```
task_for_pid(mach_task_self(), pid, &target);
mach_vm_read(target, virtual_offset, xfer_vmsize, &local_address, &local_size);
```

Comment: Do you consider disabling SIP as an option?

Comment: @Mr_Pouet, I'm aware of this option, but i'd rather use some alternative that keep sip activated (for security reasons). in fact, i want to imitate a  debugger such as lldb that can dump the entire process into file while the SIP is up. I assume that there's another way to read remote process memory (with root privileges of course)